# How to trigger only the current button from multiple buttons with the same function name - Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a button that show/hide the password field, I gave given the same function name to all the button that show/hide, So when I click on a specific textbox show/hide button, it triggers all the textbox instead of the current one.

How do I only make the current clicked button's textbox to be triggered

HTML

[image]

TS

[image]

Comment: You need to maintain three variables for showtext one for each

Comment: Okay sir , and then ?

Comment: Welp, have you though of instead of sharing the same state across all the input fields, split it into individual values for each of them?

Comment: you mean like 3 variables ? Yes sir i did , But in that case only the first button is getting triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `textTypeOld = 'text', textTypeNew = 'text', textTypeRepeat = 'text'` initially

And in the html, send the string to the function changeText like this

```
changeText("Old") // for old password
changeText("New") // for new password
changeText("Repeat") // for repeat password
```

and in your method,

```
    changeText(name: string) {
    if(name === "Old") { 
     this.textTypeOld = this.textTypeOld === 'text' ? "password" : "text";
    } else if (name === "New") {  
     this.textTypeNew = this.textTypeNew === 'text' ? "password" : "text";       
    }
    else { 
this.textTypeRepeat = this.textTypeRepeat === 'text' ? "password" : "text";    
    } 
  }
```

Also, you need to changes the type attribute for your input tags and the comaparisons in [ngClass] accordingly

Comment: @ThanveerShah if you truly want to learn something, check my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you share the same state for all the input fields is your issue, so the solution is as simple as keeping an individual value for each of them.

The question is now, how can you do this in an effective manner? My approach would be with a simple directive:

```
import{Directive,HostBinding,Input}from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: "input[passwordToggler]",
  exportAs: "passwordToggler"
})
export class PasswordToggler {
   @Input("passwordToggler")  
   @HostBinding()
   type: string;

   get visible(){return this.type === "text"; }

   toggleVisibility(){
      if(this.type === "text"){
        this.type === "password";
      }else{
        this.type === "text"; 
      }
   }
}
```

Once you declare it in the corresponding module, you could use it as:

```
<input passwodToggler="text" #oldInputToggler="passwordToggler"/>
<i [ngClass]="oldInputToggler.visible ? 'bla-text' : 'bla-password'" 
    (click)="oldInputToggler.toggleVisibility()"><i/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass $event from your html to the function call as an argument to get the instance

```
changeText($event)
```

and in your component.ts file, you will have the instance of the element which triggered your event.

Answer (score 0):

simply try to write a toggle directive that toggles between `fa-eye` and `fa-eye-slash` classes:

directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appToggleIcon]'
})
export class ToggleIconDirective {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }
  private flag = true

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick($event: Event) {
    this.flag = !this.flag;
    if (this.flag) {
      this.renderer.removeClass($event.target, 'fa-eye');
      this.renderer.addClass($event.target, 'fa-eye-slash')    
    }
    else {
      this.renderer.removeClass($event.target, 'fa-eye-slash');
      this.renderer.addClass($event.target, 'fa-eye');
    }
  }
}
```

usage:

```
<span>
  <i class="fa fa-eye" appToggleIcon>Button3 </i>
</span>
<br>
<span>
  <i class="fa fa-eye" appToggleIcon>Button2 </i>
</span>
<br>
<span>
  <i class="fa fa-eye" appToggleIcon>Button1 </i>
</span>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbajpw): check that by clicking the buttons it's class is changing.